# How can I re-use the output of one query in another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider the following snippet. I use `stuff()` to generate a list of fields. I use this same list in the following query.

```
select top 1
  stuff((
        select ',' + 'D.[' + ColumnName + ']'
              from #report_fields a
              where a.FieldType like 'X' or a.FieldType like 'Y'
              for XML path('')),1,1,'') as document_fields
  from #report_fields a
;


-- returns a fieldlist: D.[AAA], D.[BBB], D.[CCC], ...

select
    D.[AAA], D.[BBB], D.[CCC], ...
into
    #document_fields
from
    Document D
group by
    D.[AAA], D.[BBB], D.[CCC], ...
```

My problem: I need the fieldlist in the second query to be dynamic. I want to inject the output of `stuff()` directly into the `select...from document` query. What is the most straight-forward way of doing this? Can I put the fieldlist in a variable (never done this before in SQL) or do I need a dynamic query (which I am trying to avoid for many reasons).

You help is greatly appreciated.

[edit]

```
declare @fieldlist nvarchar(max)
select top 1 @fieldlist = 
  stuff((
        select ',' + 'D.[' + ColumnName + ']'
              from #report_fields a
              where a.FieldType like 'Text' or a.FieldType like 'Boolean'
              for XML path('')),1,1,'')
  from #report_fields a

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'select ' + @fieldlist + ' into #document_fields from Document D     group by ' + @fieldlist
exec sp_execute @sql
```

Comment: No, the second one.  You need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Too bad, ... this will really be ugly.

Comment: Then just make it look "pretty" :)

Comment: Any time you think you need a "dynamic field list" or dynamic sql it's a sign that something's wrong. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Note that reporting tools show a UI but store the complete SQL (parameterized of course). They *don't* try to pass field lists around

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic select statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560083/dynamic-select-statement)

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560083/dynamic-select-statement .

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has to be done via dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @Fieldlist NVARCHAR(MAX)

select top 1 @Fieldlist = 
  stuff((
        select ',' + 'D.[' + ColumnName + ']'
              from #report_fields a
              where a.FieldType like 'X' or a.FieldType like 'Y'
              for XML path('')),1,1,'')
  from #report_fields a

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = 'select '
    + @Fieldlist + '
into
    #document_fields
from
    Document D
group by '
   + @Fieldlist

   EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error `Procedure expects paramater @handle of type int`?

Comment: You'd need to post the sql you're using - the one I posted above works for me.

Comment: I have added the SQL i'm using to the OP :-)

Comment: @Pr0no, you are missing the "sql" at the end of `sp_execute`. It should be `sp_executesql` which is what Dave is showing in his answer.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that. I really did not see this. However, even though this works I cannot access `#document_fields` in a next query. Is look as if it is only available in `@SQL`? If so, this is a real problem because I need `#document_fields` throughout the rest of my script.

Comment: You can make it a global temp table instead `##document_fields`, or use a real table and make it a staging table.